# Using the output of if statement (cmp) in a cp command

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, cp, cmp

I am trying to use the output of an if statement as input for a cp command, but it does not seem to work. My code is:

```
for fname in $(find $1 -name "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG")
do
  filename=$(basename $fname)
  if cmp $2/$filename $fname; then 
    cp $fname $2/$filename.JPG
  fi
```

the output I am getting is

```
lel//IMG_0039.JPG dir/dir2/IMG_0039.JPG differ: byte 212, line 1 
lel//IMG_2317.JPG dir/dir/IMG_2317.JPG differ: byte 212, line 1
```

and I want to copy only those two files while giving them `.JPG` suffix, so they don't overwrite the existing ones in `$2`, however it copies all the files in folder `$1` to folder `$2`, while giving them the `.JPG` suffix, so now instead of having copy of the different one I have copies of the same files only that they have suffix `.JPG`

I think the `cp` statement is incorrect, as the `cmp` only gives the difference between the files and then executes the `cp` if there is a difference. I already copied the files with a `for` loop, now I am trying to rename and copy the different ones that have same names with the same `for` but with if statement.

Comment: you should try to be more explicit here: try to provide an example of output when running the above and why you think it doesn't work. Secondly, it could be very beneficial for who's reviewing this to have the ability to test it for themselves by having an example setup you can compare against.

Comment: please update your original question including this information, it's a bit difficult to read otherwise, thanks :)

Comment: have you tried to use `cmp -s` ? that should only give you the exit status for the command. Also I'm wondering have you tried to check manually what's the output of two files that _should_ be identical?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `if ! cmp...`, since cmp succeeds if the files are the same.

Comment: BTW, consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually care about the *output* of `cmp`, only its exit status. If the exit status is non-zero, then the files differ and you presumably want to do the copy. Also, don't bother with `find` here.

```
shopt -s globstar
for source in "$1"/**/IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG; do
   filename=$(basename "$source")
   target="$2/$filename"
   if ! cmp -s "$source" "$target"; then
       cp "$source" "$target"
   fi
   # cmp -s "$source" "$target" || cp "$source" "$target"
done
```

The `!` negates the exit status, as `if` executes the body if the condition has a zero exit status. Since you want to execute when `cmp` has a *nonzero* exit status, we negate it first.

Be sure to quote all your parameter expansions. Leaving them unquoted will break your code if you happen to have a file name like `$1/more files/IMG_9342.JPG`.

Comment: Maybe also highlight the importance of proper quoting. The OP's script will break in horrible ways if you attempt to process files whose names contain shell metacharacters. This one is fine, i.e. every variable is in double quotes.

Comment: As such `if cmp` was not wrong at all, only slightly clunky.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why I switched to `||` (habit)? `if` is clearly more readable and thus more appropriate for an answer like this.

Comment: It worked it is `!` all I needed. I will make sure I use quotation in future. Many thanks!

Comment: Don't iterate over `find` like that; it's why I switched to using a simple pattern. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).